# Running a lambda in a loop

Tags: java, lambda

I am creating an event by providing a `Instant` of time.

```
serviceContainer.consumeEvent(event ->
        event.setPayload(new TriggerCalculation(Instant.ofEpochMilli(serviceContainer.currentTimeMillis())
)));
```

However, I would like to add a fixed interval of time to the `Instant` and create a new event with the new `Instant`.

```
serviceContainer.consumeEvent(event ->
        event.setPayload(new TriggerCalculation(Instant.ofEpochMilli(serviceContainer.currentTimeMillis()).plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
        )));
```

However, I cannot do this in a for loop since index `i` needs to be final:

```
for(int i=1; i<7; i++){
    serviceContainer.consumeEvent(event ->
            event.setPayload(new TriggerCalculation(Instant.ofEpochMilli(serviceContainer.currentTimeMillis()).plus(i, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            )));

}
```

How can loop a lambda in java if I want to increment a value within the lambda?

Comment: Assign `i` to another variable in the line before and use that in the lambda.

Comment: You can make a final `TriggerCalculation` outside of the lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IntStream.range` for this

```
IntStream.range(0, 7)
            .forEach(i -> serviceContainer.consumeEvent(event ->
                    event.setPayload(new TriggerCalculation(Instant.ofEpochMilli(serviceContainer.currentTimeMillis()).plus(i, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
                    ))));
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the integer out of the lambda

```
for(int i=1; i<7; i++){
    final TriggerCalculation tc = new TriggerCalculation(Instant.ofEpochMilli(serviceContainer.currentTimeMillis()).plus(i, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    serviceContainer.consumeEvent(event -> event.setPayload(tc));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<7; i++){
    final int newI = i;
    serviceContainer.consumeEvent(event ->
            event.setPayload(new TriggerCalculation(Instant.ofEpochMilli(serviceContainer.currentTimeMillis()).plus(newI, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            )));

}
```

Or this:

```
IntStream.range(0, 7)
    .mapToObj(x -> Instant.ofEpochMilli(serviceContainer.currentTimeMillis()).plus(x, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
    .map(TriggerCalculation::new)
    .forEach(x -> {
        serviceContainer.consumeEvent(event ->
            event.setPayload(x));
    });
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the `IntStream.range`, suggested below, is not preferred?

Comment: @SSF You _could_ argue that streams have some overheads, but not using them might be a micro-optimisation.